# Regex to find only specific URL among various

Tags: regex

What RegEx will match images src only from 'myurl.com' ?

The closer I got was this:

Live test: http://regex101.com/r/bR0lH2/1

RegEx:

```
<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>
```

Code sample:

```
<html>
...
<br>
</b><br>
<a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f6582954.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://myurl.com/a/b/c/53e39f658291a.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f660a74d.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://myurl.com/a/b/c/53e39f660a716.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f66a1cdd.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://others.net/a/b/c/53e39f66a1ca6.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f67265ee.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://others.com/a/b/c/53e39f67265b3.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f67ad28f.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://myurl.com/a/b/c/53e39f67ad255.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f6838b67.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://myurl.com/a/b/c/53e39f6838b2b.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f68c564f.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://others.com/a/b/c/53e39f68c5618.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
 <a href="http://example.com/a/53e39f69630bc.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://myurl.com/a/b/c/53e39f6963085.jpg" alt="" border="0"> ... ... 
...
</html>
```

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right:

```
<img[^>]+?src\s*=\s*[\"'](http:\/\/myurl\.com.+?)[\"'].*?>
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tO3jS6/2)

This one would be a bit better though:

```
<img[^>]+?src\s*=\s*([\"'])(http:\/\/myurl\.com.+?)\1.*?>
```

[regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tO3jS6/3)

It ensures the quotes match, but it matches the url in `$2`.